# Can we change the title text of the vote buttons

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, user-interface, stackexchange

I just noticed that the title text (displayed on mouse hover) of the up- and downvote buttons are currently "This answer is useful" and "This answer is not useful". While they're useful for most SE sites, they don't make sense on PPCG. Is there any way we can change these texts?

Comment: Duplicate of this answer: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8362/32686

Comment: Should [feature-request] be added to the linked question? If not, I'm not sure whether to call this a duplicate or not.

Comment: I am marking this as [meta-tag:status-planned] because we hope to get this change done, but we have other things we are prioritizing and don't want to overload the CMs. This change is either very easy or requires dev work to make it customizable.